# XAML Collapsed bullet point list with hyperlink

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.8

Need some pointers on XAML styling for a collapsed bullet point list with a hyperlink to display all data items, i.e. show only the first option by default, with some hyperlink text which when clicked, would display the remaining items in the list.
E.g.:

**Collapsed List**

- Option 1

  [Click me](https://www.google.com)

**Expanded List on clicking "Click me"**

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for. Generally this is not a "Please write code for me" website

[image]

That said, here's some code

It's not terribly difficult to do what you're asking. You just need to create a custom user control. Below is the Xaml and Xaml.cs for a custom user control I made for you

SampleCollapsedList.xaml.cs

```
public partial class SampleCollapsedList : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
            public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
            public string FirstItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return ListItems != null && ListItems.Count > 0 ? ListItems?.First() : string.Empty;
                }
            }
    
            public ObservableCollection<string> ListItems
            {
                get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ListItemsProperty); }
                set { SetValue(ListItemsProperty, value); }
            }
    
            public static readonly DependencyProperty ListItemsProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ListItems), typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(SampleCollapsedList), new PropertyMetadata(null,CollectionUpdated));
    
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
            public SampleCollapsedList()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private static void CollectionUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (d is SampleCollapsedList sampleCollapsedList)
                {
                    sampleCollapsedList.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstItem));
                }
            }
    
            private void OnHyperlinkClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                IsExpanded = !IsExpanded;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsExpanded));
            }
    
            private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
}
```

SampleCollapsedList.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.SampleCollapsedList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="800"
             x:Name="self">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Height="250"
          Width="500">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Visibility="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, ElementName=self, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=opposite}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstItem, ElementName=self}" />
            <TextBlock><Hyperlink Click="OnHyperlinkClicked">Click Me</Hyperlink></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Visibility="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, ElementName=self, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems, ElementName=self}"
                 BorderThickness="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock><Run>- </Run><Run Text="{Binding Path=.}" /></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Also a simple converter to make the hide show magic happen

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class BoolToVisConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(parameter is string param && param.ToLower().Contains("opposite"))
            {
                return (bool)value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. newbie to XAML so wanted some pointers to begin with.